# Finding phrases in string. Is there a more elegant way of doing this?

Tags: java, android

I'm looking to search for 2 or 3 key phrases in a string called `lastTestText` and I want to return a `Boolean`.  It works nicely with:

```
Boolean tooLong = lastTestText.contains("hour") | lastTestText.contains("min");
```

But this is going to get a bit long-winded if I have 4 or 5 phrases so I wondered if there's a more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: You can construct a regular expression in advance (which is a bit more compact), then reuse it to find the text matches.

Comment: Regex. Or just create a helper method.

Comment: 1) It's more idiomatic to use the short circuiting OR operator (||).  2) Why return the boxed Boolean rather than primitive boolean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a regular expression:

```
lastTestText.matches(".*(?>hour|min|second).*");
```

You could even check for plurals, using an expression like this: `".*(?>hour(?>s)?|min(?>s)?|second(?>s)?).*"` which would match `hour, hours, min, mins, second, seconds`.

Note, however, that it would also match `milliseconds` since it contains `seconds`. In that case the expression would become more complex because you need to use word boundaries:
`".*\\b(?>hour(?>s)?|min(?>s)?|second(?>s)?)\\b.*"`

Answer (score 1):

How about an array:

```
String[] substrs = {...};
bool found = false;
for(String s : substrs) {
    if(lastTestText.contains(s)) {
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing this with tokens, or putting the values in constants or even try both.